# Maven Dependency conflicting with validation-api-1.0.0GA & validation-api-1.1.0Final

Tags: maven, gwt, bean-validation

I am currently working on a GWT based application. And i have also used Hibernate for the same.

I am using `gwt-user2.7.0` jar which internally using `validation-api-1.0.0GA` jar.
Also i am using hibernate (**5.0.6**) version which internally using `validation-api-1.1.0-Final` jar.

Now both the jars are conflicting in my application. I am using maven.

**Question**: How i will write my pom.xml that `gwt-user-2.7.0` use only `validation-api-1.0.0GA` and hibernate should use `validation-api-1.1.0-Final` jar.

Comment: Thanks Matteo. I am very new to stack exchange. Would you have any solution for the above question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have a single pom file where you defined `gwt-user.2.7.0` and hibernate this is not possible...Cause you can't have two different versions of the same artifact on your classpath otherwise the result is randomizing usage of the version...

Comment: @khmarbaise You should put that as an answer. Splitting client (GWT) and server code is a good practice that unfortunately too few people follow.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a single pom file where you defined `gwt-user.2.7.0` and hibernate this is not possible...Cause you can't have two different versions of the same artifact on your classpath otherwise the result is randomizing usage of the version..